# Example of an indecomposable module which is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm looking for an example of a module which is indecomposable but not simple. I know that simple modules are indecomposable.

Comment: The ring of upper triangular matrices acting on the module of column vectors?

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$ as $\Bbb Z$-modules?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ can be decomposed as n copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ which is also a submodule. $\mathbb{Z}$ is neither decomposable or has a submodule.

Comment: Both the examples given by @Arthur are good. The first one is not $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and the integers certainly have proper submodules.

Comment: Here is the [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/modules/search/results/?H=31&L=4) for indecomposable nonsimple modules.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a simple module and $E(S)$ be its injective envelope. Then every nonzero submodule of $E(S)$ is indecomposable; this is a generalization of the example in comments about $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, because the injective envelope of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ contains each of those groups as subgroups ($p$ a prime).

If $R$ is a commutative noetherian ring, then an injective indecomposable module is of the form $E(R/\mathfrak{a})$, where $\mathfrak{a}$ is an irreducible ideal ([Theorem 2.4 in a paper by Matlis](http://msp.org/pjm/1958/8-3/pjm-v8-n3-p13-p.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

For $K$ a field, let $A\in M_n(K)$ be a matrix consisting of a single Jordan block of size $n\geq 2$. The abelian group $K^n$ becomes a left module over the polynomial ring $K[X]$, by setting $f.v:=f(A)v$ for $v\in K^n$ and $f\in K[X]$. This module is indecomposable, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890548/factorization-of-a-finite-representation-of-kx-into-indecomposable-represent). It is not simple, as every eigenvector of $A$ generates a proper submodule.

More generally, for $R$ a PID, any $R$-module $R/(p^n)$ with $p\in R$ a prime element and $n\geq 2$ yields an indecomposable and non-simple $R$-module.

**NB:** I say 'more generally' since the above $K[X]$-module is isomorphic to the $K[X]$-module $K[X]/(f_A)$ where $f_A$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a good generalization of Arthur's comments would be

> Let $R$ be any ring which isn't a division ring but only has trivial idempotents.  Then the module $R_R$ is indecomposable but not simple.

It's not simple because it's not a division ring.

It's not decomposable because decomposability [requires the existence of nontrivial idempotents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727175/idempotent-endomorphisms-generate-a-direct-sum-decomposition) in $End(R_R)\cong R$.

That includes local rings and domains (the ones that aren't division rings) so examples are quite prolific.