# Factorization of a finite representation of $k[x]$ into indecomposable representations.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A:=k[x]$ (a $k$-algebra). We know every finite representation $(\rho, V)$ of $A$ is determined by $\rho(x):V\to V$. By the Jordan Normal Form theorem, $\rho(x)$ can be written as a Jordan normal matrix under some basis. Let $J_1, \dots, J_r$ be Jordan blocks of this matrix.

Each Jordan block $J_i$ determines an invariant subspace $V_i$ and $(\rho_{V_i},V_i)$ is a subrepresentation. Now I have two questions:

(1) How to prove that each $(\rho_{V_i},V_i)$ is an *indecomposable*(not irreducible) representation?

(2) Are different $(\rho_{V_i},V_i)$ mutually nonisomorphic? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: $V_i$ and $V_j$ can be isomorphic representations if the Jordan blocks $J_i$ and $J_j$ are the same.

Comment: If $V_i$ were decomposable, say, $V_i=X\oplus Y$, then $\rho(x)|_X$ and $\rho(x)|_Y$ would give rise to at least two different Jordan blocks.

Comment: @Batominovski Why is that?

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks for pointing that out! Are Jordan blocks of the same size but different eigenvalues not isomorphic?

Comment: How did you prove the existence and uniqueness (up to rearrangement) of the Jordan normal form for a square matrix (over an algebraically closed field)?  I am guessing that you assume that $k$ is algebraically closed, right?  Otherwise, you may not be able to get  a Jordan block.

Comment: If the eigenvalues are different, then they are obviously not isomorphic representations.  The actions of $x$ have to be different, as the characteristic polynomials are not the same.

Comment: @Batominovski  This brings me more questions... How is the characteristic polynomial related to the action of $x$?

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic representations of $k[x]$, then let $f:U\to V$ be an isomorphism of $k[x]$-modules.  Thus, $f(x\cdot u)=x\cdot f(u)$ for all $u\in U$.  In addition, if $p(x)\in k[x]$ acts trivially on $U$, then $$0=f(0)=f\big(p(x)\cdot u\big)=p(x)\cdot f(u)\text{ for all }u\in U\,.$$  As $f$ is surjective, $p(x)$ must also act trivially on  $V$.  Since Jordan blocks with distinct eigenvalues have relatively prime characteristic polynomials, the representations associated to these blocks cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Jordan blocks of size one in fact gives you irreducible submodules. Only Jordan blocks of size greater than one are associated to indecomposable subspaces

Answer (score 3):

One only has a decomposition into Jordan blocks if the characteristic
or minimum polynomial factors into linear factors over $k$.

The characteristic polynomial of a Jordan block matrix equals its
minimum polynomial and is $(x-\lambda)^n$ where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue
and $n$ is the size of the block. If this were decomposable as a representation,
then each factor's minimum polynomial divides $(x-\lambda)^n$, so the
factors have minimum polynomials $(x-\lambda)^a$ and $(x-\lambda)^b$
for some $a$ and $b$. Each of $a$ and $b$ is $<n$ as each is at most the
dimension of the appropriate invariant subspace. But that means the
original representation has minimum polynomial $(x-\lambda)^{\max(a,b)}
\ne(x-\lambda)^n$, a contradiction.